# Why is my .bin file being overwritten when I read data from it? (Java)

Tags: java, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I made my own data structure called a User. I am trying to store Users in a .bin file using FileInputStream and FileOutputStream. I am successfully storing a single user when a button is pressed, but then when I close the application and go to read my Users and recognize login info, the .bin file turns blank.

I know that the .bin file is not empty after the program closes, but then when I try to read the file I get a EOFException. Here is my code to read objects from the file:

```
public void loadUsers() {
    try {
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
      boolean endOfFile = false;
      while (!endOfFile) {
        try {
          System.out.println("loaded a user!");
          User person = (User) ois.readObject();
          Users.addUser(person);
        } catch (EOFException e) {
          endOfFile = true;
          ois.close();
        }
      }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
  }
```

Here is my code to write objects to the file:

```
public void storeUser(User person) {
    boolean endOfFile = false;
    try {
        new ObjectInputStream(fi).readObject();
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        endOfFile = true;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (!endOfFile) {
        System.out.println("Appending!");
        try {
            AppendingObjectOutputStream aos = new AppendingObjectOutputStream(fo);
            aos.writeObject(person);
            aos.flush();
            aos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Writing a new file!");
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);
            oos.writeObject(person);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

AppendingObjectOutputStream is just a small subclass of ObjectOutputStream I made that overwrites writeStreamHeader() so that there is no header placed in my file when try to write more users. I don't think this is related to the problem because I have yet to write a User onto a file with Users already written on it.

Comment: How are you creating `fo`?

Comment: Equally important, how are you creating `fi`? If the `fi` is the same you used in `loadUsers()`, then the stream is already at end, so `endOfFile` will always be true, and you'll never use `AppendingObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: In the constructor for the class both these methods are in, I create both fi and fo. They are private instance variables

fi = new FileInputStream("coins.bin");
fo = new FileOutputStream("coins.bin");